# How to convert the widget into a image file in Kivy?

Tags: android, python, kivy

### Hello!

I'm currently at the point of upgrading the Simple Paint project and I was wondering if there is any way to save the screen or current state of the widget as an image file. I'd like to implement that but I have no idea where to start.

---

I'd appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [kivy documentation for widgets](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html), you can simply use the `.export_to_png` function to save a widget as an image.

> **export_to_png**(filename, *args)
>
> Saves an image of the
>   widget and its children in png format at the specified filename. Works
>   by removing the widget canvas from its parent, rendering to an Fbo,
>   and calling save().
>
> **Note**
>
> The image includes only this widget and its children. If you want to
>   include widgets elsewhere in the tree, you must call export_to_png()
>   from their common parent, or use screenshot() to capture the whole
>   window.
>
> **Note**
>
> The image will be saved in png format, you should include the
>   extension in your filename.